# Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext - not a web app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Here is the build.gradle file. I have removed comments and sensitive data. 
Still receiving the "missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory Bean" error.

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.5.4")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.de.gliderpilot.gradle.semantic-
   release:gradle-semantic-release-plugin:1.3.1")
    }
    }
    dependencies { 
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') 
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail') 
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf') 
    { 
                exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' 
        }             
        runtime files ('/libs/ojdbc8.jar') 
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    }   
    plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17"
    id "de.gliderpilot.semantic-release" version "1.3.1"
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'  
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    group = 'com.usps.informed-delivery'
    dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-xml')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test')
    compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-api')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-oxm")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')
    compile('libs/ojdbc8.jar')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')    
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test') 
    }
    publishing {
    publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
    }
    }
    }
    artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http:whatever'
    publish {
    repository {
        if (version.toString().endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
            repoKey = 'snapshots'
        } else {
            repoKey = 'releases'
        }
        username = "" 
        password = "" 
    }
    defaults {
        publications('mavenJava')
        publishArtifacts = true
        properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']           
        publishPom = true
    }
    }
    resolve {
    repoKey = 'jcenter'
    username = "" 
    password = "" 
    }
    }
    sonarqube {
    properties {
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "readers-digest-generator"
    property "sonar.projectName", "Readers Digest Generator"
    }   
    }
```

Posting the build.gradle file per request. I have tried to resolve by putting 
spring.main.web-environment-=false in aplication.properties file and app.setWebEnvironment(false) in BatchApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot assumes it's a web app unless you configure it otherwise.  The documentation (found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-create-a-non-web-application) illustrates that you can either configure your application to not be a web app either programatically via calling `SpringApplication#s setWebEnvironment(false)` or via setting the property `spring.main.web-environment=false`

Comment: Thanks Mr. Minella! ... loved you in "Pro Spring Batch". Can't wait for the movie! I will attempt to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Comment: Pleas stop adding comments and just update your question.  This is unreadable so we really can't help this way.

Comment: I can't read any of this.  You need to update your question with this in order for us to help you.

Comment: OK. I have edited the original post with the build.gradle file. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike, I was wondering if you could take another look at this, sorry about the jumbled posts, I was just so excited to hopefully get some assistance with this that I was trying to post the build.gradle file in the comments.